# SPA. Is it real single page application inside MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I noticed that many people think that SPA is just only interactive pages (click button - get dialog). SPA also means transferring between pages (with changing URL, supporting history, etc). Gmail is good example of it.

*Does* ASP.NET MVC 4 give implementation of whole SPA or just "click button - get dialog" (like in their [template](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/getting-started-with-spa/spa-walkthroughs/walkthrough-getting-started-with-spa))?

If yes, where I can read docs or see example? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release of VS 2012 shows us that answer is NO... The template is absent.

Here I find a really good explanation how to create SPA:
http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spa